# Android Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() not work?

Tags: android

This is my previous code

> private static final String ROOTPATH          = "/data/data/";

and I want to change it to use Environment:

> private static final String ROOTPATH          =
>   Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/";

but i get this result:

```
> 08-12 10:53:09.131: E/SQLiteDatabase(1051):
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error
> (code 14): Could not open database 08-12 10:53:09.131:
> E/SQLiteDatabase(1051):   at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
> 08-12 10:53:09.131: E/SQLiteDatabase(1051):   at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
> 08-12 10:53:09.131: E/SQLiteDatabase(1051):   at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
> 08-12 10:53:09.131: E/SQLiteDatabase(1051):   at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
> 08-12 10:53:09.131: E/SQLiteDatabase(1051):   at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
> 08-12 10:53:09.131: E/SQLiteDatabase(1051):   at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
> 08-12 10:53:09.131: E/SQLiteDatabase(1051):   at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:804)
> 08-12 10:53:09.131: E/SQLiteDatabase(1051):   at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:789)
> 08-12 10:53:09.131: E/SQLiteDatabase(1051):   at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
> 08-12 10:53:09.131: E/SQLiteDatabase(1051):   at
> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
```

and Here is my work:
    ........
    ........

```
private static final String ROOTPATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/";
private static final String DB_NAME_INDBNAME    = "database.jpg";
private static final String DB_NAME_OUTDBNAME   = "database.db";

...... 
public synchronized static NOLDatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if(dbHelper == null) {
         dbHelper = new NOLDatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    return dbHelper;
}


private NOLDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME_OUTDBNAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    this.context = context;
}


public void createDatabase() {
    if(!isDatabaseExited()) 
    {
        Log.v(GlobalConfig.TAG, "NO database");
        getReadableDatabase();
        copyDataBaseFromAsset();
    } else {
        Log.v(GlobalConfig.TAG, "Has database");
    }
}


private boolean isDatabaseExited() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase( ROOTPATH + DB_NAME_OUTDBNAME, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        checkDB.close();
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {}
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}


private synchronized void copyDataBaseFromAsset() 
{
    int length                  = -1;
    byte[] buffer               = new byte[1024];
    AssetManager am             = context.getAssets();

    try 
    {
        InputStream assetsDB    = am.open(DB_NAME_INDBNAME);
        String outFileName      = ROOTPATH + DB_NAME_OUTDBNAME;
        OutputStream dbOut      = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

        while ((length = assetsDB.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            dbOut.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        dbOut.flush();
        dbOut.close();
        assetsDB.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        Log.e( GlobalConfig.TAG, "copyDataBaseFromAsset error, is say: "+e.toString() );
    }
}
```

createDatabase() is called from outSide use getInstance(). Is there have any wrong or missing code?  How should I solve this issue?

Big Thanks~!

Comment: have you add this <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/> permission in AndroidManifest.xml ?

Comment: Yes, I have added~ but still have this problem

Comment: Please [use `SQLiteAssetHelper`](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) for packaging a database with your app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Change

```
 super(context, DB_NAME_OUTDBNAME, null, DB_VERSION);
```

to

```
 super(context, ROOTPATH + DB_NAME_OUTDBNAME, null, DB_VERSION);
```

in your `NOLDatabaseHelper` constructor and change `ROOTPATH` to

```
ROOTPATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/";
```

Comment: Can someone please suggest how this answer can be improved?

Comment: Hi, I tried this and fix the issue, but may I know, whats the difference between Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() and Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()

Comment: `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` give you the file for external storage and `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()` gives you the path to that file.

Comment: Thanks for your help! one more thing, If user unmounted SDcard, which Environment path should I use in this case? should I use getDataDirectory()?

Comment: `getFilesDir()` provides you the path for internal storage for your apps